# How to decide if a plot twist worth doing?

Tags: fiction, plot

There's a major piece of information in my story, which I could either make tell right away - or else keep it a secret, and use it as a plot twist later. I'm having a hard time choosing which way to go.

In my particular case, there are two brothers travelling to rescue a prince; the thing is, he's not just a prince - he's their brother, and they're princes too.

I feel like this is something I could build up into a good surprise, a real "A-HA!" moment. On the other hand, it can also get awkward (e.g., if I use one of the brothers as a POV character, I need to show how *he* thinks of the prince), and I'm just not sure how effective this is in practice.

I can't surprise myself; I can only try to figure out what will surprise the reader. **How can I tell if a plot twist I'm writing (or planning) is good and worthwhile?**

Comment: What would be your purpose in keeping it as a surprise? It sounds like a point all your POV charactersknow. What benefit is there to the story from withholding that information?

Comment: I suppose the purpose would be emphasise that if my two travelers fail, the whole kingdom is going down. Benefit to the story? Well I don't know if it adds much benefit.

Comment: I see this a lot, stories that hide an essential piece of information from the reader when all the characters in the story know it. I find it manipulative and I usually stop reading once I realize this is happening. If the characters all know the secret, the reader should know it too. If you want to keep a secret from the reader, then keep it from your main character, too. That way the reader gets the reveal as the character does.

Comment: @KaiMaxfield wrote a follow-up question, addressing a particular point my rewrite cut out of this question: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/21360/how-can-i-keep-secret-a-major-detail-known-to-the-pov-protagonist

Comment: The follow-up question was really @Standback's work. My name is on there; but I can't take the credit for it. I hope that the answers are of some help. It looks like there are about as many who don't like this sort of a twist as those who do.

Answer (score 4):

If any of the viewpoint characters know the brothers' identities, this won't work as a plot twist. It might work if you use viewpoint characters who are not privy to the information.

In general, a revelation makes good plot twist only if it *surprises the current viewpoint character.* That is, the reader learns the information at the same moment when the viewpoint character learns it.

If it's a revelation only to the reader, and if the viewpoint character already knows the thing that's being revealed, that's not a plot twist. That's an authorial swindle. That's you (the writer) playing unfair with the reader. Readers get very annoyed at that.

But if a character is shocked and surprised by some revelation, that's characters playing unfair with each other. And that's delightful.